# Add new files through VS IDE configured with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

It's really annoying having to exit my IDE, create a new file, add it to cmake lists, re-run cmake, and then hop back in the IDE any time I want to add a new file. I want to use the add new file option from inside Visual Studio. The problem is if I do this, it adds the file in the cmake's output directory (since that is where the generated sln and vcxprojects are located). This means the file is deleted next time cmake is ran.

What I want is for Visual Studio to place new files in the source directory cmake uses to generate the project files to begin with. It would be really nice if it automatically updated the cmake lists file as well. (I know you can use glob patterns to copy all the .h or .cpp files, but that solution doesn't work for us, we list each file directly).

How can I configure VS through cmake to change the new file destination to the 'actual' location and not the output directory while automatically updating the cmake lists?

Comment: VS does support that scenario in CMake mode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Open two Visual Studios

1. Run `cmake`   and open the generated Visual Studio project.
2. Open a local folder -> select your cmake folder .

In Visual Studio -> Right Click -> Switch to cmake target View.

Right Click cmake project(executable):

[image]

The second `add -> new item` option:

[image]

Visual Studio automatically edits your CMake project

```
add_executable (CMakeProject1 "CMakeProject1.cpp" "CMakeProject1.h" "Header.h")
```

Then re-run cmake  in `cmd`.

And in the first project, there will be a notification: reload all
[image]